# How do I perform general pattern assignments in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

```
$ cat names
projectname_flag_jantemp
projectname_flag_febtemp
projectname_flag_marchtemp
projectname_flag_mondaytemp
$
```

Perl code:

```
my $infile = "names";
open my $fpi, '<', $infile or die "$!";
while (<$fpi>) {
    my $temp = # what should come here? #
    func($temp);
}
```

I want temp to have

```
jan
feb
march
monday
```

respectively.

The pattern always remains the same

```
projectname_flag_<>temp
```

How should I do the extraction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
my ($temp) = /^projectname_flag_(.+)temp$/;
```

Note that the parentheses around `$temp` are needed so that the pattern match runs in list context. Without them, `$temp` would end up containing just a true or false value indicating whether the match succeeded.

More generally, a pattern match in list context returns the captured subpatterns (or an empty list if the match fails). For example:

```
my $str = 'foo 123   456 bar';
my ($i, $j) = $str =~ /(\d+) +(\d+)/;  # $i==123  $j==456
```

Comment: Just remember to check if the match succeeded.

Answer (score 7):

If compatibility with older `perl`s is needed, I would use [FM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3830335/how-to-perform-general-pattern-assignments-in-perl/3830391#3830391) (just make sure the match succeeded by checking if `$month` is defined).

As of 5.10, you can use named captures:

```
my $month;
if ( /^ projectname _flag_ (?<month> [a-z]+ ) temp \z/x ) {
    $month = $+{month};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about named captures.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (<$fpi>) {
        chomp;
        s{projectname_flag_(.*?)temp}{$1};
        # $_ will now have jan, feb, ...
}
```

Comment: How can I make this operate on a variable instead of `$_`? For example, input is in `$inp` instead of `$_` and output should also go to `$out` not `$_`?

Comment: @Lazer: `( $out = $inp ) =~ s{projectname_flag_(.*?)temp}{$1};`

Answer (score 0):

I guess:

```
/^projectname_flag_([a-z]+)temp$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (<$fpi>) {
  my ($temp) =($_ =~ m/projectname_flag_(.*?)temp/);
  func($temp);
}
```

Comment: -1 for using `.*` when `.+` (or a more restrictive pattern) would have been more appropriate.